# Laravel query groubBy condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a dB query where I would like to `groupBy()` only when conditions are met without using `union` because of `pagination`.
Unfortunately `groupBy()` seems to only work when called on the entire query outside of the loop.

This was made for dynamic filtering from `$filterArr`.  Depending on the array I need to select from different columns of the table.
When the `$key=='pattern'` I would need the distinct results from its column.

the query looks something like this

```
select `col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3` 
from `mytable` 
where (`color` LIKE ? or `pattern` LIKE ? or `style` LIKE ?)
group by `col_2` //<< i need this only for 'pattern' above and not the entire query
```

Heres the model:

```
// $filterArr example
// Array ( [color] => grey [pattern] => stripe ) 

$query = DB::table('mytable');
$query = $query->select(array('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'), DB::raw('count(*) as total'));

$query = $query->where(function($query) use ($filterArr){
  $ii = 0;
  foreach ($filterArr as $key => $value) {
    if ($key=='color'){
      $column = 'color';
    }else if ($key=='style'){
      $column = 'style';
    }else if ($key=='pattern'){
      $column = 'pattern';
      $query = $query->groupBy('col_2'); // << !! does not work
    }

    if($ii==0){
      $query = $query->where($column, 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%');
    }
    else{
      $query = $query->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%'); 
    }

    $ii++;
  }
});

$query = $query->orderBy('col_2', 'asc')->simplePaginate(30);
```

Comment: This entire loop looks a bit odd. Do you mind explaining the logic behind it? Also (sidenote) you can have `orWhere` in all cases it's functionally identical to what you have currently

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using `DB::table` instead of a `Model` ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti can you explain `Model` please

Comment: @weber Laravel official documentation about [Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#defining-models)

Comment: @matiaslauriti the table names and other non standard circumstance surrounding this project.

Comment: @weber If I did understand what you posted, the only SQL query on top of your code is the current resulting query, right ? If that is the case, could you write another one being the one you need ? I am at a loss what specific SQL query would you like.

Comment: imho, Its quite complicated when i read your eloquent, maybe  using raw query is better. Concatenate string in your logic, then pass it as raw query at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your code a bit:

```
$query = DB::table('mytable');
$query = $query->select(array('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'), DB::raw('count(*) as total'));

$query = $query->where(
   collect($filterArr)
      ->only(['color','style','pattern'])
      ->map(function ($value, $key) {
          return [ $key, 'like', '%'.$value.'%', 'OR' ];
      })->all()
)->when(array_key_exists('pattern', $filterArr), function ($query) {
   return $query->groupBy('col_2');
});

$query = $query->orderBy('col_2', 'asc')->simplePaginate(30);
```